# .htaccess file is not working in my Server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, server

My site is located in `https://itjmovies.com/milan/public/` and I want to rewrite the URL by `.htaccess` file. From `https://itjmovies.com/milan/public/` To `https://itjmovies.com/milan/` but it is not working.
And also `https://itjmovies.com/milan/public/auth/index.php?page=new` To `https://itjmovies.com/milan/public/auth/new/` but this is also not working.

I have kept my `.httaccess` file in `/www/wwwroot/itjmovies.com/milan/.htaccess`

My `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /public/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^public/auth/([a-zA-Z]+) /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thank You :)

Comment: A `RewriteRule` works on the _relative_ path requested in the URL. Your first rule's pattern tries to match an absolute path though. Try `^(.*)$` instead or make the leading slash optional (`^/?(.*)$`) so that the rule can be used in distributed configuration files (".htaccess") or central configuration files (the http server's host configurations) likewise.

Comment: Please clarify... should `public` be part of the visible URL? I would assume not, although you appear to be trying to implement this as a "redirect" in `.htaccess`? "And also `/milan/public/auth/index.php?page=new` To `/milan/public/auth/new/`" - but that doesn't make sense - it would seem to be in reverse? Although you are implementing it the other (correct) way round in the directive? But you have `page=new` in your description, but `new=...` in the code sample?

Comment: @MrWhite Sorry for the errors, I have modified the question. Please review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that your edit made your question any clearer. In your question description the stated rewrites (from/to) appear to be the wrong way round to what I think they are intended (and conflict with the order in which you have written the directives), but anyway...

My assumptions:

- `/public` should not be part of the visible URL. Although your site is located in the `/milan/public` directory. You are making requests of the form `/milan/<anything>`.
- You need to internally rewrite all requests from `/milan/<anything>` /to `/milan/public/<anything>`.
- Requests of the form `/milan/public/auth/<something>/` (note the trailing slash, as stated in your example) should be internally rewritten to `/milan/public/auth/index.php?page=<something>`

I would have 2 `.htaccess` files. One in the `/milan` subdirectory that simply rewrites/forwards requests to the `public` subdirectory. And another `.htaccess` file in `/milan/public` that handles rewrites that are specific to your application.

For example:

```
# /milan/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# Forward all requests to the "public" subdirectory
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

```
# /milan/public/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite "auth/<something>/" to "auth/index.php?page=<something>"
RewriteRule ^auth/([^/]+)/$ auth/index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The `.htaccess` file at `/milan/public/.htaccess` also serves to prevent a rewrite loop when requests are rewritten to the `public` subdirectory by the `.htaccess` file in the parent directory. This is because mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default.

The `QSA` flag is only required if you are expecting query strings on the original request.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (1st argument) matches the URL-path relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file.

---

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /public/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
> RewriteRule ^public/auth/([a-zA-Z]+) /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

A few notes on your attempt - which is close, but has a few crictical errors:

- The URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash (when used in `.htaccess`), so the regex `^/(.*)$` will never match.
- The first rule is also an external redirect (ie. exposes the `/public` subdirectory) which doesn't seem right. Do you really want `/public` in the visible URL - if so then you should be linking directly to the `/public` subdirectory, not relying on a redirect?
- The first rule is redirecting to `/public` in the document root, not `/milan/public`.
- Once corrected, the first rule will also result in a rewrite-loop (500 Internal Server Error) as it will repeatedly rewrite the request... `public/public/public/<something>` etc.
- The second rule is also rewriting to `/index.php` in the document root, not `/milan/public/auth/index.php`.